# What kind of luck are Hanako and Botan getting in the opening?

Tags: japanese-language, anne-happy

In the opening sequence of Anne-Happy, Hanako and Botan are both shown holding omikuji, those little papers that Japanese people draw at shinto shrines that forecast their luck.

[image: hanako with omikuji]
[image: botan with omikuji]

I know that omikuji have different types and levels of luck, and given that the theme of the series is unlucky moe girls, I assume Hanako and Botan are both getting bad luck. But just how bad is it? Which exact classes of omikuji did they draw?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither of them are traditional omikuji results. Hanako has "hazure", which translates roughly as "miss" or "fail". Botan's is "sune", which I can't find a useful meaning for. "Sune" is Japanese for shin, or leg, and the only other meaning I can find is in reference to being a shin-biting bug, which is slang for being a mooch, which doesn't seem to fit.

EDIT: In episode 3, Botan does shout out "sune!" when her shin cracks, although she also breaks about three other bones in the same episode so I'm not sure why the shin would be singled out.

Comment: I haven't watched this, but would it make sense if "sune" were the stem of 拗ねる【すねる】?

Comment: Not really, but that did lead me to 拗ね者, a perverse individual, cynic or misanthrope, which is a little closer. All of the students in this class have ridiculously bad luck in some form - Hanako loves animals but they don't exactly love her back, and Botan is accident-prone to the point where she is an expert at bandaging herself. She also acts quite creepy at times, which I don't think is quite the same as 拗ね者 but is the best theory I have so far.